# geoportail with Configurable Map Viewer

Tags: kml, api, configurable-map-viewer

I am new in GIS programming, I have to created a geoportail  with the Configurable Map Viewer (CMV). I want to add my KML layers but they don't appear in the map. Below is the part of my code

```
operationalLayers: [{
            type: 'kml',
            url: "http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/ban/MapServer/",
            title: 'banques',
            options: {
                id: 'libelle',
                opacity: 1.0,
                visible: true,
                outFields: ["*"],
                mode: 0
            },
            editorLayerInfos: {
                disableGeometryUpdate: false
            },
            legendLayerInfos: {
                exclude: false,
                layerInfo: {
                    title: 'My layer'
                }
            }
  }, {
            type: 'kml',
            url:    'http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/ban/MapServer',
            title: 'Region Rabat Sale',
            options: {
                id: 'key',
                opacity: 1.0,
                visible: true,
                mode: 0
            }
  },

   ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you've shown in your code is not for kml. It is for an ArcGIS Server MapServer. If that is the source of the data, you should use `type: 'dynamic'`.